# Number of words of length N that reduce to the identity in a specific Coxeter group

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Suppose we have a Coxeter group whose diagram is given by a simplex.
In other words,
$G = \langle g_1,...g_k | (g_i)^2 = e, (g_ig_j)^3 = e \rangle$.
How many words of length $N$ simplify to the identity?  What is the recursion/generating function?
The case $k=2$ is easy, because the group is finite; the corresponding generating function is $E(x) = \frac{1}{3} [2/(1-x^2) + 1/(1-4x^2)]$.
I expect $k=3$ is likewise readily doable.  Is there a general solution?
What if we change the relations to $(g_ig_j)^m = e \,\,\forall i,j$?

Keep in mind the word problem is solvable for Coxeter groups.

More generally, if I give a group element in this group whose shortest word is $g_{i_1}...g_{i_p}$, how many words of length $N$ are equivalent to it?

Comment: While technically this is solvable, I don't think it's going to be easy. This question may be better suited for mathoverflow.

Comment: This might be one of those things where a more complicated problems is actually easier. Let us instead consider the same question for an arbitrary element rather than the identity. Now, the number of words starting with some generator $s$ and reducing to the identity with length $N$ is the same as the number of words of length $N-1$ reducing to $s$, giving us a recursion (and the case with all products of order $3$ should be nicely symmetric so the answer should be the same regardless of which generator one starts with).